# Определение типов

Tags: c++

Я понимаю, что лучше читать, чтоб знать, но просто от любопытства хотел бы знать сейчас: Почему?..

```
 typedef int Rank;    // правильно
 using Temp = double; // правильно
 typedef void (*P)(); // правильно
```

А вот это:

```
 using (*f)() = double;
```

неправильное определение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что суть `using`-алиаса в том, чтобы связать с **именем** некий существующий тип.

А в записи `using (*f)() = double;` на месте имени стоит `(*f)()`, что не является корректным идентификатором в C++, а потому именем типа быть не может.

Это действие примерно того же калибра, что создание переменной под названием... ну, скажем, `-x`. Представьте, насколько безумным должен быть (если вообще **может** быть) парсер, чтобы различать обращение к этой переменной и применение унарного минуса к `x`.

Comment: хороший ответ,  но пример с   а + b  думаю не совсем подходящий. Ведь это выражение  говорит:  "'это обьект, который получается в результате складываний двух обьектов, и он после этого выражения уничтожится". А вот (*f)()  означает, что  f  является типом указателей на функцию без аргументов.  Если я тут не прав, рад буду услышать возражения...

Comment: Хотя я могу сам себе возразить:  выражение (*f)()  само по себе ничего не означает ...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan да, до полного определения типа "указатель на функцию" этой записи не хватает типа возвращаемого значения. Поэтому оно для описаний типов даже и выражением-то не является, в отличие от примера, который демонстрирует полноценное выражение. Хотя проблему оба вполне иллюстрируют.

Comment: вот так лучше  и понятней!..